# Create Macro or Module to separate or extract multiple values in excel

Tags: excel, module, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel sheet with about 5000 likely voters within a county. The columns have the address, city, state, zip code, last name, first name, etc. Within this county are about 10 towns.

My task is to find the addresses within the county of the residences who are within town limits of these 10 or so towns. So far I have been looking at a map and individually searching for each street that is within the town limits of each town, then copying and pasting them and writing the name.

Needless to say, this takes hours. Is there a way to automate this? 
I need to get the address of the voter and his/her first and last name, to send mail to them.

Comment: it looks it can be done very easy without macros, try VLOOKUP() - or try anything else, and post results as simoco wrote

Comment: okay so to be most clear, the excel sheet is filled with likely voters, with the columns having the address, city, state, zip code, last name, first name, etc. I need to separate the ones within the town limits somehow in order to send them mail. So i need to get the address and the name of the person out of this data. I do not know how to do this with the exception of manually searching for the street names which are in the town limits and then copying and pasting the results. This is very tedious as there are hundreds of them. I have only a basic knowledge of excel so i need help

Comment: So I want to input the name hundreds of streets and have it ouutput any houses on those streets and the name of the person who lives there. If a screenshot is needed to help I can provide that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer might be to just filter the street column and copy/paste and then delete those filtered rows.  Maybe there's more to your question but that's how I'd do it.